# Unable to load the Entity classes using spring boot 3.1.2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have created a new spring boot project with version 3.1.2 and using spring data jpa

I have added Entity class  and annotated with @Entity complete project structure is correct but when i run the application I am getting the RuntimeException

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentManagementSystemApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentController': Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentService': Error creating bean with name 'studentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentRepository': Error creating bean with name 'studentRepository' defined in com.marolix.StudentManagementSystem.repository.StudentRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.marolix.StudentManagementSystem.entity.StudentInfo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:716) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:696) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.marolix.StudentManagementSystem.StudentManagementSystemApplication.main(StudentManagementSystemApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
```

Later I created a new project with version 2.7.1, and the application is running fine.

What is the reason for this? Is there any way to resolve this issue
I am using Windows operating system.

Comment: Are you by any chance still using `javax.persistence.*` annotations in your code instead of `jakarta.persistence.*`?

Comment: Thanks for the response
Yes I am using javax.persitence for @Entity,@Id etc

Comment: You need to switch to `jakarta.persistence.*`, that is one of the big breaking changes in Spring Boot 3 (and Hibernate 6) compared to previous versions.

Answer (score 4):

There was a massive change between Spring Boot 2 and 3 regarding persistence framework called JPA (Java Persistence API aka Jakarta). As a minimum change you should rename all imports `javax.persistence` to `jakarta.persistence`.

For more details you can check the [Hibernate 6.0 Migration Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add below annotation with your package of entities on your main class or on a configuration class.

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.marolix.StudentManagementSystem.entity")
```