# Spring Boot JPA issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to run my Spring Boot Java project, but i get these errors when i try to run it:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'availabilityRepository' defined in com.island.lendingportal.repository.AvailabilityRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.island.lendingportal.model.Availability

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'availabilityService' defined in file [C:\Users\Lucas\IdeaProjects\javap3\lending-portal\target\classes\com\island\lendingportal\service\AvailabilityService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'availabilityRepository' defined in com.island.lendingportal.repository.AvailabilityRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.island.lendingportal.model.Availability

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.island.lendingportal.model.Availability
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:463) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]

I have added those as dependencies in my pom.xml file, and my AvailabilityRepository consists of this:
package com.island.lendingportal.model;

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "availability")
public class Availability {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "availability_ID")
    private Long availabilityId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_ID", nullable = false)
    private Item item;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_ID")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "availStartDate")
    private Date availStartDate;

    @Column(name = "availEndDate")
    private Date availEndDate;

    @Column(name = "isBooked")
    private boolean isBooked;

//and then constructors, getters and setters
```

This is my application file

```
package com.island;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.island.lendingportal.model")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.island.lendingportal.service")
public class LendingPortalApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LendingPortalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my availabilityRepository

```
package com.island.lendingportal.repository;

import com.island.lendingportal.model.Availability;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AvailabilityRepository extends JpaRepository<Availability, Long> {
    // You can add custom query methods here if needed
}
```

This is my availability model

```
package com.island.lendingportal.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "availability")
public class Availability {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "availability_ID")
    private Long availabilityId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_ID", nullable = false)
    private Item item;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_ID")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "availStartDate")
    private Date availStartDate;

    @Column(name = "availEndDate")
    private Date availEndDate;

    @Column(name = "isBooked")
    private boolean isBooked;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Long getAvailabilityId() {
        return availabilityId;
    }

    public void setAvailabilityId(Long availabilityId) {
        this.availabilityId = availabilityId;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setAvailStartDate(Date availStartDate) {
        this.availStartDate = availStartDate;
    }

    public Date getAvailStartDate() {
        return availStartDate;
    }

    public void setAvailEndDate(Date availEndDate) {
        this.availEndDate = availEndDate;
    }

    public Date getAvailEndDate() {
        return availEndDate;
    }

    public void setBooked(boolean booked) {
        isBooked = booked;
    }

    public boolean isBooked() {
        return isBooked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us how your application is set up, particularly any JPA-related annotations like `@EntityScan` or `@EnableJpaRepositories`, if they are used? `AvailabilityRepository` implementation, configuration files, etc. The more details you share the easier to identify what exactly causes this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load the Entity classes using spring boot 3.1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76819918/unable-to-load-the-entity-classes-using-spring-boot-3-1-2)

Comment: @RuslanZinovyev i updated the thread with more code - i also tried changing the imports from javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence.

Comment: I see some inconsistency, in your first `Availability` class example you imported:
`import javax.persistence.*;`
In the second example of `Availability` class you used
`import jakarta.persistence.*;`

Comment: Can you please confirm what import you are using in your `Availability` class, I think your problem is related to this.