# Failed to load ApplicationContext when trying to build a SpringBoot CRUD application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, crud

I created a simple CRUD application using Spring but when I try to build it using `mvn clean install`, it throws the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.2:test (default-test) on project todolist-crud:
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] Please refer to /Users/dawoodtrumboo/todo-crud/server/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
> [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Report file

```
            -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: todolistcrud.todolistcrud.TodolistCrudApplicationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.71 s <<< FAILURE! - in todolistcrud.todolistcrud.TodolistCrudApplicationTests
todolistcrud.todolistcrud.TodolistCrudApplicationTests.contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@727dcc64 testClass = todolistcrud.todolistcrud.TodolistCrudApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [todolistcrud.todolistcrud.TodolistCrudApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@3c77d488, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5ab956d7, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@6e9175d8, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@7bba5817, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@4a6b257f], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'taskController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'taskRepository': Error creating bean with name 'taskRepository' defined in todolistcrud.todolistcrud.TaskRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class todolistcrud.todolistcrud.Task
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskRepository' defined in todolistcrud.todolistcrud.TaskRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class todolistcrud.todolistcrud.Task
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class todolistcrud.todolistcrud.Task
```

TodolistCrudApplication

```
    package todolistcrud.todolistcrud;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TodolistCrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodolistCrudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Repository

```
    package todolistcrud.todolistcrud;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
}
```

Controller

```
    package todolistcrud.todolistcrud;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

// import todolistcrud.todolistcrud.TaskRepository;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/todos")  // Corrected endpoint path
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        return taskRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Task> getTaskById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return taskRepository.findById(id)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Task createTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Task> updateTask(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Task updatedTask) {
        return taskRepository.findById(id)
                .map(task -> {
                    task.setDescription(updatedTask.getDescription());
                    task.setCompleted(updatedTask.isCompleted()); // Use isCompleted() instead of isIsCompleted()
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(taskRepository.save(task));
                })
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteTask(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return taskRepository.findById(id)
                .map(task -> {
                    taskRepository.delete(task);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
                })
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
}
```

How could I make this run?

Entity

```
    package todolistcrud.todolistcrud;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String description;
    private boolean isCompleted;

    public Task() {
        // Default constructor for JPA
    }

    public Task(String description, boolean isCompleted) {
        this.description = description;
        this.isCompleted = isCompleted;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return isCompleted;
    }

    public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
        isCompleted = completed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", isCompleted=" + isCompleted +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the plugin (maven-surefire-plugin) added in the pom.xml file. Please verify the plugin version and check if it is installed correctly in the local repository. Alternatively, you can try running `mvn clean install -DskipTests` to skip the entire unit test phase and build the project

Comment: Tried both ways, the application didnt run after skiping the test and after install the plugin correctly , there still remain the Failed to load Application Context.

Comment: "the application didnt run after skiping the test" What happened?

Comment: As the failure is happening when you run a particular test, you'll need to edit your question and add that test class.

Comment: After skipping the test , I tried running its using `java -jar todo-crud.jar` but it showed Error: Unable to access jarfile todo-crud.jar. Also update the test report above

Comment: What Spring Boot version is it? Please share pom.xml or gradle file.

Comment: Please check this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76819918/unable-to-load-the-entity-classes-using-spring-boot-3-1-2/76819955#76819955